# Can't indirectly include images in LyX

Tags: graphics, pdftex, lyx

In a folder `example/` there are subdirectories `example/chapter1/`, `example/chapter2/` etc.

Some images occur in more than one chapter, hence I made a subdirectory `example/images/` where I put the images, let's call it `example/images/image.pdf`.

In the base directory there is `example/images.sty` providing a command for including the image (and does some more stuff I stripped for this MWE):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../images/}}
\def\myimage{\includegraphics{image.pdf}}
```

Now some file in a subdirectory, let's say `example/chapter1/main.tex`, uses that command like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{../images}
\begin{document}
\myimage
\end{document}
```

When compiling with pdflatex on the command line this works. But when using LyX this doesn't work: import `example/chapter1/main.tex` into LyX (so `example/chapter1/main.lyx` is created) and try creating pdflatex via LyX and it claims `File image.pdf not found`. (And when using `\includegraphics` directly in `main.tex` instead via `images.sty` it works, too.)

Comment: A comma should separate the graphics paths. `\usepackage{../images}` is not right. You should only use `\usepackage{images}` and ensure the relevant directory is searched by TeX.

Comment: I have never seen an example using a comma separating the `\graphicspath`; and a classic trap of `\graphicspath` is that it ignores everything outside the `{}`, hence it does not matter whether one uses a comma or not. If I use `\usepackage{images}` TeX doesn't find it because it is not a global package but one belonging to this single project. And `\usepackage{../images}` works, otherwise it would neither tell me that it could not find the file when trying to call pdflatex in LyX nor successfully compile when calling pdflatex manually.

Comment: For a MWE need only one of the paths in `\graphicspath`, anyway, so I changed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that as far as LyX is concerned `.sty` files are raw LaTeX, hence only the file gets copied to the temporary directory where LyX does the compilation but not the dependencies referenced in that file - these get resolved only for `.lyx` files.

I went with using an absolute path `\graphicspath{{/home/username/latex/example/images/}}`. That's going to give me trouble only when I move it to a new directory or computer - and then I would have only to change the directory reference.

Comment: This comment comes 8 years later, but it seems the problem that you reported hasn't been solved. Worse yet, our workaround (which I would really like to avoid actually, since I work cross-platform sometimes) isn't working anymore. (As detailed in my recent question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635192/lyx-with-graphicspath-bad-identical-latex-with-graphicspath-good-possible-bu )

Comment: For whoever reads this: I was just pointed to this bug tracker https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8895 and it seems LYX DOES NOT SUPPORT GRAPHICSPATH. For me, this is insane, because it clearly makes Lyx more cumbersome to use that LaTeX in this use case! According to a (very brief) discussion on the bugtracker, stick with includegraphics and use search & replace as the only option to update folder path. Really annoying.